# How to clear all GCM device groups or registration IDs?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Is there an easy way to either remove all device groups for an App Engine app, or remove the registration IDs for all device groups?

The problem is that there are multiple registrations for a single device causing duplicate messages.

Comment: From the doc here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications I dont think there are functions to do this.